# getting this error after includig cloud_firestore_web: ^2.4.3 in dependencies in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

## The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

## Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
firebase_auth: ^3.1.3
firebase_core: ^1.7.0
cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
provider: ^6.0.1
cloud_firestore_web: ^2.4.3

**error**
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-2.4.3/lib/cloud_firestore_web.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.4.2/lib/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-2.4.3/lib/src/load_bundle_task_web.dart:4:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.4.2/lib/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-2.4.3/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.4.2/lib/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-2.4.3/lib/src/collection_reference_web.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.4.2/lib/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-2.4.3/lib/src/field_value_factory_web.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.4.2/lib/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-2.4.3/lib/src/document_reference_web.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.4.2/lib/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-2.4.3/lib/src/query_web.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.4.2/lib/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-2.4.3/lib/src/transaction_web.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutterapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.4.2/lib/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.
.
.
.
.
.
.
(i could not kept all error message due to limit)

Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)

i have tried these solutios but didnt work:
1)https://betterprogramming.pub/dont-panic-when-flutter-generates-a-bad-file-for-you-e5e314c2b01
2)i deleted the file(generated_plugin_registrant.dart) in lib folder which was automatically generated when i run the app

Comment: Try flutter clear or removing `^2.4.3` since sometimes new dependencies might not be compatible with older ones

Comment: did it but no use